# iPhone + alternative to drop downs

Tags: iphone, drop-down-menu

I am developing native iPhone app.

I have one requirement that, there are 5 drop downs in the screen, where user will select each value and based on that there will be a graph generated on screen.

Also the drop downs are cascading, meaning that depending on value selected in upper drop down, the values in lower drop downs will change.

If it was a web app than, I had no problem as we have drop downs available.

But it is a native iPhone app and we don't have drop down in iPhone SDK.

Please suggest me some other alternative to achieve the same.

Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cocoa iPhone Way would be to use a hierarchy of table views coupled with the [delegate pattern](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently drop downs are out and "wizards" are in, where it asks you a question at a time then pops out your chart.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UITableView` and when user selects a row you can load another view in which list of item is displayed...each new view's item should be loaded from previous view... by that you can cascading it also...